# Dynamic multiple Vue multiselect options override issue

Tags: vue.js

When use vue multiselect dynamically with more than one the options array override previous.

Comment: Please provide your question with the code

Comment: It would help to see more details, what you've tried, maybe list some code. Please have a look at - [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)